# How to find an address in coredump?

Tags: gdb

I have a coredump file which is more then 4Gb. I want to find all the occurrence of an 64 bit integer. Will be helpful if you can share info on this.

Will opening coredump as a text file and searching will help ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure you can, just use "find" command of gdb

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Searching-Memory.html

Comment: Thanks. Version 6 dont have but i could find it in version 6.8. Will mark it answered in 7 minutes. Do you know other ways to search in version 6 ? Like copying all symbol to file and doing a search and so ?? thanks again

Comment: file will be binary data, you may be able to find your integer by searching for it - see http://debugmo.de/2009/04/bgrep-a-binary-grep/

Comment: In find full coredump what will be the values of start_addr and  end_addr ?